# How to extend SAP Fiori Elements with custom pages

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am fairly new to SAP Fiori. I was able to complete the setup of the list report. Everything is working, even the CRUD functions. However, I need a custom button, which will display a new custom page. I've already extended the report to include a custom button. The button is working when I press it but I don't know how to proceed.

I know it should be something related to routing for freestyle apps and somehow I understand the settings, however, I don't know how to integrate it with a list report, since it is not a freestyle application.

Can someone bring some light?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?